# Store video on iPad and play video without using native iOS 5 Videos app

Tags: ipad, video, uti

Is there a combination of 2 applications which would allow me to transfer videos from my computer to my iPad and play the video files on my iPad without involving the native iOS 5 "Videos" application?

I dislike the native iOS 5 "Videos" application because it doesn't allow organizing video into a file structure, and "Videos" only allows viewing a thumbnale of the video.  I don't want to see a thumbnale - just text.  I have 40-50 videos at a time, so the root folder in Videos gets cluttered.

"File Browser" and many other file utility apps will copy video files from my computer to my iPad.  But I can't find a player which will play the videos from a file browser.

Looking for a combination of 2 applications which would allow me to transfer videos from my computer to my iPad and play the video files on my iPad without involving the native iOS 5 "Videos" application.

Comment: can you use DropBox to store the videos and then VLC player to play them.

Comment: That might work, but dropbox would create a new problem.  My LAN connection is extremely fast while dropbox is much slower at residential internet speed.  I prefer to transfer files from my computer directly to my phone without involving a server on the internet.  15 GB of files over the internet would take at least a day of maxing out my pipe's bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

Get [Air Video](http://www.airvideoapp.com) from the App store. Install the client on your Mac and point it to the directory with your videos. The iPad client will give you the option of streaming it or saving it on the iPad

Answer (score 0):

### [Mediapad Pro](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mediapad-pro-photography-video/id394760312?mt=8)

This can be used to transfer viodeos and images to the ipad using iTunes.

here is a vido showing how the app works

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZaPjt1xSxbw&feature=player_embedded#!

You can then watch

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [CineXplayer](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id384098375?mt=8)?  It can read every kind of video and audio format. You can add files from any computers with iTunes to it and play it "locally" on your iPad when ever you want. You can even take the movies files from the iPad and copy them to an other computer!

It works on both the iPhone/iPod Touch and the iPad.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id384098375?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

### [GoodReader](http://www.goodiware.com/goodreader.html)

will do the job:

> MANAGE FILES! GoodReader lets you create folders, move, copy and
> rename your files; zip, email and unzip them; plus send your files to
> other apps.
>
> TRANSFER FILES! Within moments of downloading GoodReader, you’ll be transferring files in a number of ways: directly
> from your computer over a USB cable or WiFi connection, from the
> Internet or from email attachments. It also easily integrates with
> iDisk, Google Docs, Dropbox, SugarSync, box.net and other WebDAV, AFP,
> FTP and SFTP servers.

Selecting a video will call the iOS Apis and play the video. When it's finished you return to GoodReader

And you get one of the most bestest PDF viewers for iOS ;)

[image]